# What is the relation between interface MTU and received packets length?

Tags: networking, ethernet, mtu

Let's say that two hosts A and B communicate via an Ethernet medium. Host A has MTU 1500 and host B has MTU 1300.

If A is sending a packet with length 1500, will host B receive it?

Comment: Is this a pure Ethernet packet or is it IP over Ethernet? (It makes a difference.)

Comment: my questions comes in the context of an ISIS packet, so AFAIK no IP.